# Search for single character

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have several cells in Excel 2007 that contain long sentences with the letter `r` between words. For example:

> "The product code is r A23000"

I tried typing "r" in the Find box but the results show not only single "r" but any words / sentences containing "r" - e.g. `I was trying to get this done`.

How can I search for an isolated `r`, or is there any Excel add-in that could help, or any VBA code to list the results line-by-line, like the Find box does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest method would be to search for the letter *r* with a space before and after the character. 
e.g: " r "

[image: Before]

[image: After]

I replaced all instances of the letter r with a space to demonstrate.

Comment: You're welcome, and for future reference this should work with most programs. :D